# Nuxt.js generate: Cannot read property 'props'

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt.js `npm run generate` fails with next output even on the `npx create-nuxt-app` project:

```
i Generating pages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            03:24:14

 ERROR   /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    03:24:14

TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at D:\projects\web-nuxt\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.prod.js:6:9329
    at Tt (D:\projects\web-nuxt\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.prod.js:6:9512)
    at Tt (D:\projects\web-nuxt\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.prod.js:6:9924)
    at Function.Cn.t.extend (D:\projects\web-nuxt\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.prod.js:6:30431)
    at l (server.js:1:9992)
    at Module.<anonymous> (70395f0f40e296b112f1.js:1:131453)
    at r (server.js:1:194)
```

OS: Windows 10, Ubuntu

Packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^2.10.2",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.9.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.5.0"
  }
```

Steps:

1. npx create-nuxt-app
2. npm run dev
3. npm run generate

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6755

Comment: @Muhaddis thanks for valuable input from your side, but there's no code except one created by default with npx create-nuxt-app

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but as workaround rollback to nuxt 2.8 to be able to use Nuxt:

```
npm i -S nuxt@2.8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your vue file call other file like "~/src/pages/js/some.js", then
 Nuxt expects the file put under the tree of pages/ has a property of "props".